# low level math, about probability

Tags: probability

let say we have $2$ boxes, box A and box B

probability of getting a blue ball from box A is 1/3 
probability of getting a red ball from box B is 1/20

and 3 blue balls = 1 red ball

so which box has higher rate of getting a red ball?

the answer provided is box B

and here is the explanation

"probability of getting a blue ball is 1/3 and since we need 3 blue balls for one red ball so the chance is 1/3*1/3*1/3 = 1/27 and 1/27 is lower than 1/20"

but why 1/27 and not 1/9, i mean averagely we can get 3 blue balls every 9 try right??

Comment: How often may we draw from box $A$?

Answer (score 0):

The probability of 3 independent events to occur after each other is the product of their probabilities.

In your case, let say that getting a blue ball is event A. So P(A,A,A)=P(A)P(A)P(A)=1/3 *1/3* 1/3=1/27.

Here is a well explained link where you can learn more about the [probability of multiple events](http://www.mathplanet.com/education/pre-algebra/probability-and-statistic/probability-of-events).

==EDIT==

The rate of blue balls is:

RateBlueBalls=#BlueBallsInTrials/#Trials , but #BlueBallsInTrials=#Trials*Pr(BlueBall)

Hence: RateBlueBalls=(#BlueBallsInTrials*Pr(BlueBall)/#Trials = Pr(BlueBall)

Comment: but P(A,A,A) is the event that draws ONLY 3 balls right? that is why 1/3*1/3*1/3=1/27.

each 1/3 equivalent to one draw, and 1/27 is the chance to get three blue balls in three draws

but getting 3 blue ball in 3 draw is different from getting 3 blue balls in 20 draws.

for example, given 20 draws, which box produce more red ball?

Comment: The rate is the same as the probability, at least in your case. Check my edit.

Comment: so we can get 6.66 blue balls from box A if we draw 20 time right?

and 6.66 = 2.2 red balls

so in another word, in 20 draws, the box A produce more red ball than box B

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I see that you may be new to this website. If you found an answer useful, consider up-voting it or selecting it as answer.